# Get Titles of all forms in vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to load the titles of all the forms in the current web application

Below is the code.

```
 Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)()
    Dim formType As Type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form")
    For Each t As Type In sender.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
        If UCase(t.BaseType.ToString) = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
            Dim frm As New Form
            frm.Name = t.Name
            cmbSelectForm_frmMultiLanguageUtility.Items.Add(frm.Text)

        End If
    Next
```

cmbSelectFrom_frmMultiLanguageUtility loads empty values at runtime.

Please suggest

Comment: You would have to add them to collection. Easier it would be to add them to array of names when loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the application forms and add the window title to your combobox:

```
    For Each t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
        If t.BaseType.Name = "Form" Then
            cmbSelectForm_frmMultiLanguageUtility.Items.Add(CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form).Text)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you Chase Rocker, you saved my day